# Could not read ./composer.json file_get_contents(./composer.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mpgE.png)i want to delete laravel package from my pc i used linux...

When i run this command $composer remove laravel/laravel

this error appears  "Could not read ./composer.json  file_get_contents(./composer.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory "

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed it globally you can simply remove it by `composer global remove laravel/installer`

If you have installed it via composer project you simply remove the directory.

Comment: i don't remember ... i run your command but the same error appears

Comment: Then just delete the directory where the laravel project is installed.